# Dialogflow response without a request

Tags: dialogflow-es, slack, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Is it possible that dialogflow sends a message on Slack without having someone to send it a request? For example this is a common application that a user talks to bot and the bot responds back. But what if the bot realizes that nobody has talked to him for some time on Slack and automatically sends a message to slack channel.

Comment: You've tagged this as actions-on-google, but you're talking about Slack. Is this meant for either of those platforms specifically?

Comment: @Prisoner removed actions on google tag. I am using dialogflow-fulfillment library and want to use slack integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Dialogflow works on a request-response model. So something in slack needs to trigger the request in order for it to respond.